# Passive temperature limit supervision with electronic readout

Tags: switches, sensor, temperature

I have a sensor component, which should not be heated over 60°C, otherwise it might start drifting for weeks. I want to supervise the temperature of the component, even if the device it is built in is turned off. I would like to have the status to be electronically readable when the device is turned on again.

So far the solutions I've been able to come up with:

- [chemical indicator stickers](https://www.thermometersite.com/overheat-detection) - not electronically detectable, the sensor has to be placed in a visible position --> not ideal for the application
- battery powered low-power uC monitoring the temperature - additional fw needed, significantly increases system complexity
- battery powered temperature supervision IC - increases system complexity, so far I have found nothing like it

Are there any components like the chemical indicator sticker, which are electronically readable (e.g. like a switch)? They do not have to be resettable, but it is nice to have. How are they called? Are there any commercially available temperature supervision IC-s, which can store the maximal temperature without any master necessary for operation? (As pointed out in the comments, not looking for recommendations, only yes/no, maybe how this class of components is called to be able to google it.)

Comment: **Site rules/advice** - *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.*

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, the problem description was already included in the original question. I edited the question part nonetheless.

Comment: *Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve* - you are still asking for product recommendations.

Comment: Looks like you are talking about temperature data loggers, maybe (high) temperature data loggers

Comment: There are battery-powered data loggers designed to monitor shipments of perishable goods etc. however sourcing them is outside the rules of this site. You could design one, but it might be a lot of work for a one-off unless your motivation is learning.

Comment: Asking "Are there any commercially available..." is just a backhanded way of asking for a product recommendation. No one can answer "No" and the only way to reasonably answer "Yes" is by mentioning a specific product.

Comment: I disagree. The term "thermal fuse" below was enough to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like this could be a good application for a thermostat, depending on what your space constraints are.

Mechanical thermostats (like bimetal thermostats) come in some varieties which are manually resettable. You use it just like a typical switch in your circuit. The manual-reset kind can sometimes be bulky since they must also house the reset button.

If you don't care about resettability, there are "thermal fuses" that are designed to break their connection once they exceed a certain temperature (similar to how some passive fire sprinklers work). These also behave just like switches, but are typically one-time use and would need to be replaced.

In the realm of battery-op, there are also solid state thermostats that could be used, like the TMP303. Alternatively, a simple circuit using a thermistor or sensing IC like the LM35 in conjunction with a comparator and latch may fit your application. That is definitely edging away from simplicity, though.